# Why My combobox binding not working

Tags: c#, wpf

I Am trying to bind my combo with list, but i get nothing

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        DataContext = this;
        InitializeComponent();

        List<item> list = new List<item>();
        list.Add(new item() {id = 1,name = "stack"});
        list.Add(new item() { id = 2, name = "overflow" });
        comboBox.DataContext = list;
        comboBox.SelectedIndex = 0;
    }

     <ComboBox x:Name="comboBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="22,14,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="147" 

                ItemsSource="{Binding Path=list}" >
        <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Label Content="{Binding Path=id}" />
                    <Label Content=":" />
                    <Label Content="{Binding Path=name}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ComboBox>
```

Comment: Do not post links to external sites. Post the relevant parts of your code here.

Comment: its taking me sometimes hours to fit my code to stackoverflow Requirements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting `comboBox.DataContext = list;` and `DataContext=this` this is not how MVVM works.Also you should never access elements in the code behind this totally violates MVVM principle.

Instead you should do

```
   public List<Item> List { get; set; }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        List = new List<Item>();
        List.Add(new Item() { id = 1, name = "stack" });
        List.Add(new Item() { id = 2, name = "overflow" });

        DataContext = this; //This is the only place where you should set datacontext
    }


   <ComboBox x:Name="comboBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="22,14,0,0" 
    VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="147" ItemsSource="{Binding List}" SelectedIndex=0 >
```

Comment: are you sure..because it works well on my machine..can you post your code

Comment: your `list` is private make it public

Answer (score 1):

You have local variable as your item source. It must be a property.

**Change this:**

```
public MainWindow()
{
   ....
    List<item> list = new List<item>();
   ...
}
```

**To this:**

```
List<item> list { get; set; }

public MainWindow()
{
   ....
    this.list = new List<item>();
   ...
}
```

Also, you don't need to manually set datacontext of the combobox in the constructor (remove this line): `comboBox.DataContext = list;` You are setting the datacontext in the Xaml as: `ItemsSource="{Binding Path=list}"`

There are other issues with your code. You don't have INotifyProperty changed, as such, data will only be loaded once at intstatiation. Also, you shouldn't bind to the UI component itself as its own datacontext. Correct way to do this would be use a ViewModel class.